# C# call matlab function, result always the same

Tags: c#, matlab

I have created a C# programm which calls a matlab function and something weird happened.
The code is very simple and I just list them below:

Programm.cs:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the MATLAB instance 
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

        // Change to the directory where the function is located
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        matlab.Execute("cd " + path);

        // Define the output 
        object result = null;

        // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
        matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result, 3.14, 42, "world");

        // Display result 
        object[] res = result as object[];

        Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(res[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

myfunc.m:

```
   function [x,y] = myfunc(a,b,c) 
   x = a + b; 
   y = sprintf('Hello %s', c);
```

Every time I run the code, the output is always the same, even though I change the body of the matlab funtion or the argument values.

Is there anyone who encountered the same problem?

I use VisualStudio2019 and matlab2016.

ps.
If you find any error in my written english, please tell. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks very much.@Platypus

Comment: Try following : matlab.Feval("myfunc", 1, out result, new object[] {3.14, 42, "world"})  Then make myfunc(x)

Comment: Thank you,  jdweng. follow your advice and the code works well. But the problem mentioned above still occur.@jdweng

Comment: Are you using in matlab x[1] x[2] and x[3] now that it is an array?

Comment: I found something. Every time I run the code, a matlab command window be opened. If I close the command window before I rerun the programm, I will get the correction answer. Or else, the output will always be the same, even though i change the matlab function content.

Comment: So when you are done in c# set matlab = null.  Matlab licensing only allows one instance of the license.  Matlab will wait until one instance completes before running second.  So Feval must be running asynchronously or getting an exception.

Comment: Much thanks to you,  jdweng!@ jdweng